# Android image intent crash

Tags: android

When i try to take a picture the app is crashing.

static var:

```
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
```

function call:

```
    btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });
```

function:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

manifest:

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The crash happens when i click the `btnCapturePicture` button.
The app is webview base app, when clicking on webview button it starts the activity which contains the codes i have posted.

Thanks for any help.

**Solution that worked for me:**
removing this line from the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

And make sure you have this line:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Add crashlog please

Comment: Look into the logcat and post the exception

Comment: Guess `ActivityNotFoundException`. If so there is no app on device to capture image.

Comment: have you add permission in of CAMERA in manifest?

Comment: Hi and thanks. i did edit the post and added crashlog. 
Yes i added permission of camera in manifest

Comment: are you testing in phone or emulator?

Comment: in phone using usb cable in android studio

Comment: Add try catch to your  dispatchTakePictureIntent() and have a log statement in catch block and tell us what is the exact error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What worked for me:**

removing this line from the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

And make sure you have this line:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```